# where is the data saved during Django stack development

Tags: django, database

Maybe this is a super silly question. I am new with Django stack web app development.

I am following [Django tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views). I entered information to the backend database **via the admin page**. But some error happened later so I had to uninstall pyenv and restart. **I wonder if I can find all the information I entered which is not on any project documents.** Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're following the tutorial closely and they don't specify a database to store information in, there should be a sqlite3 database in your project file system

Comment: thanks. I am now able to open the database in vscode and see the content. : )